# Link to a javascript function on a different website

Tags: javascript

Is this possible to do? If so how?

Details: If you go to https://www.rollingvideogames.com/rent-a-video-game-trailer.html, and search for NORTH Carolina, then click 'Book Now' under any of the results, a form comes up.

Is it possible to link directly to say NORTH GREENSBORO's booking form from another page?

Comment: If the other page does not have its own URI and it's a pure javascript popup, then no, you can't

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured. thank you.